# Saber si existe un dato en sql desde python Tkinter

Tags: python, mysql, base-de-datos, tkinter, datos

estoy haciendo un proyecto de un registro medico, vinculado a `mysql` usando *Python* y *tkinter*, pero me surgió un pequeño problema, estaba a punto de terminar y recordé que hacia falta algo, el problema es que quiero que cuando se escriba el ID del medico que le corresponde al paciente, quiero que me muestre un mensaje de error mediante el método `messebox` si el ID Medico no existe en la base de datos, adjunto una imagen para una mejor comprensión [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tenia en mente es tomar el numero del ID Medico que se coloque y despues buscarlo en la base de datos para ver si existe, si existe lo añade sin problema, si no muestra un mensaje

```
 def agregar(self,nombre,segunombre,apep,apem,col,num,correo,tel,edad,medico,sintoma=""): 
    #condicion si numero de id no existe y
    #buscarlo en mysql   
    if #condicion si el ID Medico no existe: 
        messagebox.messagebox.showerror("erro","El ID del medico no existe, consulte la seccion medico para ver cada Id")
        
    else:
        cur=self.conexion.cursor()
        sql='''INSERT INTO paciente (nombre, SegundoN,APaterno, AMaterno, Colonia, Numero_casa, correo, telefono, edad, medico, sintoma) 
        VALUES ('{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')'''.format(nombre,segunombre,apep,apem,col,num,correo,tel,edad,medico,sintoma)
        cur.execute(sql)
        self.conexion.commit()
        cur.close()
```

Algunas cosas se marcan en error porque el if esta incompleto

No se si me de a entender pero es todo lo que me faltaría, o por lo menos eso creo, muchas gracias a quien lea esto, de verdad cualquier ayuda es util

#### Actualización

La consulta si la logre hacer, me regresa exactamente todo lo que contiene el medico con id 3, y nada si no existe el numero
imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Código**

```
 def idmedico(self,medico): #aqui ya recibe el entry del medico
    cur=self.conexion.cursor()
    sql="select * from medico where idMedico='{}'".format(medico)
    cur.execute(sql)
    registro=cur.fetchall()
    for i in registro: #para mostrar los datos en consola
        print(i)
```

Comment: Y cual es el código que has implementado?, has pensado en algo?

Comment: Lo que tenia en mente es tomar el numero del ID Medico que se coloque y despues buscarlo en la base de datos para ver si existe, si existe lo añade sin problema, si no muestra un mensaje, Actualizare la publicación con una imagen sobre como lo imagino

Comment: muy bien!, sin embargo el código va como texto >_<, por favor edita tu pregunta

Comment: ajajajaja perdon, es mi primera vez usando la plataforma

Comment: ok, alli solo implementas la logica en caso exista o no el `ID`, pero no haces ningun procedimiento para verificarlo

Comment: yo tengo la misma idea que tu, primero se coge el id, luego se busca en la BD y dependiendo el resultado se lanza la alerta o se inserta el valor

Comment: exacto, es lo que busco hacer, pero no se como lograrlo :(

Comment: Bueno yo no se de Tk pero te guiaré, sabes como obtener el texto de una entrada?

Comment: si, por lo menos como yo lo hago es hacer una varibale, crear un entry y en las propiedades del entry poner textvariable=(la variable que haya usado)

Comment: entra al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126364/ayuda)

Comment: me dice que ocupo 20 puntos de reputacion

Comment: :(, bueno no importe te explicare por aca

Comment: ok, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: primero el valor de la entrada `ID Medico`

Comment: luego de obtener el dato haz una consulta a la bd, teniendo esto, edita tu pregunta con tu avance

Comment: ya esta, es todo a partir de donde dice "Actualizacion;"

Comment: ahora solo pon un `if registro: print("hay registros") else:print("no hay registros")`,esto luego de obtener el registro en tu función `idmedico()`

Comment: Wow Ya quedo, muchísimas muchísimas gracias amigo de verdad muchas gracias por ayudarme te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: no te preocupes, si deseas puedes responder a tu propia pregunta :D

Answer (score 1):

## Solución:

Usar la variable de ID Medico y hacer una consulta a la base de datos, una vez realizada la consulta hacer una condición

### Código:

```
 def idmedico(self,medico): #aqui ya recibe la variable del ID
    cur=self.conexion.cursor()
    sql="select * from medico where idMedico='{}'".format(medico)
    cur.execute(sql)
    registro=cur.fetchall()
    if registro:             #Condicion si existe algo o no, si exite algo 
        print("hay registro")
        for i in registro:
            print(i)
    else:                    #Si no existe nada
        print("no hay registro")
```

#### Gracias

Muchas gracias a @Christian por ayudarme en resolverlo, de verdad gracias :D